# friendship with extern "C" function seems to require :: to qualify name

Tags: c++, friend, extern

Trying to make a `class` friends with an `extern "C"` function, this code works:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  void foo();
}

namespace {
  struct bar {
    // without :: this refuses to compile
    friend void ::foo();
    bar() : v(666) {}
  private:
    int v;
  } inst;
}

int main() {
  foo();
}

extern "C" {
  void foo() {
    std::cout << inst.v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But I was very surprised to find that with g++ 4.6.1 and 4.4.4 I have to explicitly write `::` in `friend void ::foo();` otherwise the friendship doesn't work. This `::` is only needed when it's `extern "C"` though.

1. Is this a compiler bug/problem? I wasn't expecting that behaviour.
2. If it isn't a bug why is this required, but only when it's `extern "C"` and not without it? What about the name lookup rules changes that makes this necessary?

I'm stumped. There is probably some rule for this that I can't find.

Comment: [Not the case without the anonymous namespace.](http://codepad.org/Hw7JC8Ky) And [here](http://codepad.org/9qVdlrhC)'s the testcase.

Comment: Hmm is that a bug then? I can't find anything in the lookup rules that would explain why that combination of `extern "C"` and anonymous `namespace` would need the `::` but removing either makes it unnecessary. Admittedly though my knowledge of the finer details of name lookup is hazy and this was based on searching.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - it fails with any `extern "C"` + `namespace`, not just anonymous ones.

Comment: What if you say `friend extern "C" void foo();`?

Comment: btw: I tried with gcc 4.4.0 4.4.1 4.4.2 4.4.3 4.4.4 4.4.5 4.4.6 4.5.0 4.5.1 4.5.2 4.5.3 4.6.0 4.6.1 4.7.0 and the all compile with `::` and fail without.

Comment: @KerrekSB - `friend extern "C" void foo();` gives `error: expected unqualified-id before string constant` at that line.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - comeau agress with GCC to.

Comment: Point 2 seems wrong. [The code doesn't compile for me even when `foo` is not `extern "C"`.](http://codepad.org/b42SzZkx)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - you're right, I must have made a mistake testing it. Thanks for the useful 7.3.1.2/3 reference though, I was looking for `extern` everywhere in the document to try and explain it. I guess it shows how often I end up making friends with anything outside of the current `namespace`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH deserved more than one measly upvote for testing with 14 toolchains, people c'mon! (even if he does script it \*ahem\*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `[n3290: 7.3.1.2/3]:` Every name first declared in a namespace is a
>   member of that namespace. If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class
>   first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a
>   member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The name of the friend is
>   not found by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3)
>   95) this implies that the name of the class or function is
>   unqualified. until a matching declaration is provided in that
>   namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting
>   friendship). If a friend function is called, its name may be found by
>   the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and classes
>   associated with the types of the function arguments (3.4.2). **If the
>   name in a `friend` declaration is neither qualified nor a *template-id*
>   and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the
>   lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared
>   shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing
>   namespace.** [..]

The innermost enclosing namespace is the anonymous one, and you didn't qualify the function name, so [the name is not found](http://codepad.org/9qVdlrhC).

The namespace [need not be anonymous](http://codepad.org/hcZwQ2Im), either.

Note that the `extern "C"` in the question is a red herring, as [the following also fails for the same reason](http://codepad.org/3GmDl2aq):

```
void foo();

namespace {
struct T {
   friend void foo();

   private: void bar() { cout << "!"; }
} t;
}

void foo() { t.bar(); }

int main() {
   foo();
}

/*
In function 'void foo()':
Line 7: error: 'void<unnamed>::T::bar()' is private
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
*/
```

[[alternative testcase, adapted from your original code]](http://codepad.org/b42SzZkx)

Comment: (As for _Why_, well who the frak knows)